# Unable to install pantheon-shell and elementary-tweaks due to missing dependencies

Tags: package-management, elementary, pantheon

I am on Ubuntu 14.04. I want to install two packages: `pantheon-shell` and `elementary-tweaks` but getting following error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install pantheon-shell
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pantheon-shell : Depends: slingshot-launcher but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: gala but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

```
$ sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 elementary-tweaks : Depends: gala but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: slingshot-launcher but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried this, didnt help:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Might want to mention what ppa you're using.

Comment: @doug I am using `sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:elementary-os/testing`, `sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:versable/elementary-tweaks-isis` and `sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:elementary-os/daily`. btw i just installed pantheon DE

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, in the shown order

```
sudo apt-get autoclean && apt-get clean
sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude -y upgrade
sudo aptitude install <package>
```

Comment: it did not help

Comment: it says there is nothing like `clear`

Comment: can you post your sources.list please, this might help

Comment: I corrected it, autoclean removes old unused packages and clean removes the "main" cache.

Comment: copy of sources.list [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10638453/)

Comment: I might know the problem give me a sec!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the repos have the same packages but with different versions?

I think you need APT Pinning for that, to tell apt which repo you prefer to install from.

```
ppa:elementary-os/testing
ppa:elementary-os/daily
```

This might be your problem. You need to give these repos prio's.

Comment: I have not idea how to do that

Comment: http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html